Hella 450 foglights not working, possible ground issues?
Trying to diagnose where I went wrong in wiring my Hella 450s in my 1992 Toyota Camry LE:
Lights themselves are grounded to the bolts on the front fenders, new 10mm steel bolts with copper washers, used a wire brush to clean off the paint down to bare metal, didn't use any kind of grease or anything and I did notice a little bit of white deposits around the bolts, very little though. Also grounded the relay in the same way, just below the battery tray.
The wire in the Hella harness is 18awg, not sure if this could also be causing a problem. There is a lead to the + terminal of the battery, and a 15a fuse protecting it.
I used a Toyota foglight switch on the dash (three pin, 21a @ 14VDC per the text on the switch itself), 1 lead to the relay, 1 lead to the + terminal and protected by a 5a fuse, and one to a steel bolt & copper washer and a new hole drilled into the metal frame just up from the hood release (tried to keep it as out of the way as possible). The switch has a light but when I flip it the light does not come on which makes me suspect an issue with that part of the wiring, or a bad switch.
Based on the description (can provide more details if needed), does anyone have a guess as to where I've gone wrong? I'm pretty happy with the routing of the wires, right now kinda thinking it's a ground issue but haven't been able to test them yet (need to get a multimeter). This is new to me and I'm learning as I go, so I'd really appreciate any feedback/ideas from those who have more experience than I..
Update: got a multimeter & test light. All the ground points measured 0.0 ohms and all lit up the test light. I also proved the switch terminals with the same results. The lead from the relay to the battery wasnt registering on either the test light or meter at all. May be a dumb question but is it possible that the fuses im using are too small amperage-wise? I'm definitely scratching my head since I figured the grounds were the issue and it appears they were okay after testing..

After you get a multimeter you should edit your question to say what you've found. Until then, it's just guessing. Pretend you're an electron starting at the battery, and start tracing your circuit where the electrons should be going. At some point you'll read no voltage or infinite resistance where you should have continuity, and that's where the problem is.

Update: got a multimeter & test light. All the ground points measured 0.0 ohms and all lit up the test light. I also proved the switch terminals with the same results. The lead from the relay to the battery wasnt registering on either the test light or meter at all. May be a dumb question but is it possible that the fuses im using are too small amperage-wise? I'm definitely scratching my head since I figured the grounds were the issue and it appears they were okay after testing..

Use a length of cable connected to the battery positive terminal and probe backward from the spotlights to see when the lights stop working.
You should be able to illuminate the spotlights by probing -

Directly to each spotlight positive connection
To the pin on the relay that connects to the spotlights
To the pin on the relay that activates the relay coil
To the pin on the switch that connects back to the relay coil

When you find the place that stops working, you will have narrowed down the possible faulty connections.  Report back with your results.

Update: got a multimeter & test light. All the ground points measured 0.0 ohms and all lit up the test light. I also proved the switch terminals with the same results. The lead from the relay to the battery wasnt registering on either the test light or meter at all. May be a dumb question but is it possible that the fuses im using are too small amperage-wise? I'm definitely scratching my head since I figured the grounds were the issue and it appears they were okay after testing..

If the fuse is not blowing, then the fuse size isn't the issue.  If you don't have continuity between the relay and the battery, then there is a bad connection on that wire.  If that is the wire with the fuse in it, then check from the battery to the fuse and then from the fuse to the relay to narrow it down.
